# Creating PowerShell cmdlet from C#

Tags: c#

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Beta 2. What is the relevant namespace/classes for creating a PowerShell cmdlet in C#?

I assume there is an interface or abstract class to derive from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to derive from [System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.cmdlet.aspx).

It lives in system.management.automation.dll. If you're on Windows Vista or newer, the file's in your GAC, which *can* be referenced but it's tricky. It's probably easiest to install the [PowerShell SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=50633a1f-a665-425d-923c-1a269f8ac084), and then you can reference the assembly directly from "Add Reference..." in Visual Studio. (Full path is `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`.)